# How to split a string by grouping consecutive same chars

Tags: regex, ruby, split

I have a string of consecutive same characters, like this: "aaabbc", which I want to group them in an array: ["aaa", "bb", "c"].

I've already attempted to solve it using Hash, and it really worked, but now I wonder if it is possible to solve using split and regex.

This is what I have done based in another answer from SO:

```
"aaabbc".split(/\\b([a-z])\\1+\\b/)
```

But it's giving me just the initial string in an array:

```
["aaabbc"]
```

Instead of giving each group of same consecutive characters separated by commas:

`["aaa", "bb", "c"]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer does not use `split`, but offers another alternative. You could make use of [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while):

```
"aaabbc".each_char.chunk_while(&:==).map(&:join)
#=> ["aaa", "bb", "c"]
```

This first pulls apart the string into a list of characters, then it compares the consecutive elements using `==`. This creates an array of character arrays. Finally you convert each character array back to a string using `join`.

Answer (score 7):

```
"aaabbc".gsub(/(.)\1*/).to_a
  #=> ["aaa", "bb", "c"]
```

This uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) when no block is given, in which case an enumerator is returned. In fact, this form of `gsub` has nothing to do with string replacements; the enumerator merely generates matches. It overcomes a limitation of [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan) when capture groups are present.

The regular expression reads, "match any character, saving it in capture group 1, then match zero or more characters equal to the contents of capture group 1".

Comment: Hi Is it possible to explain how this `(.)\1*+` regular expression works?

Comment: @Rajagopalan The `+` is a [possessive modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and means take everything you can find and don't give anything back if you can't get a match. The only thing it does is speed up the regex since it doesn't need to backtrack for that quantifier.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, I confess that the `+` was a relic that I forgot to remove. :-) In fact, I was not aware of "possessive modifier", so learned something. I took out the `'+'` to keep it simple. 3lim, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've learned something too, I always forget that `gsub` can be used with one argument. Which might be due to the name `sub` = substitute in my mind. I'll try to keep this in the back of my head, it's a clean solution.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, I've found that using `gsub` without a block has many uses. I think it would have wider use if it were a separate method, such as `String#each_match`, in which case there would be no need for that form of `gsub`, buts it's too late to change `gsub` in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#scan` too.
It's a bit messier than the `gsub` method, as the answer above alludes to:

```
"aaabbbbc".scan(/(.)(\1*)/)
  #=> [["a", "aa"], ["b", "bbb"], ["c", ""]]
```

because `scan` collects the matches in separate arrays, the first matched group `(.)` is on its own each time but it's a simple matter to `join` the groups up:

```
"aaabbbbc".scan(/(.)(\1*)/).map(&:join)
 #=> ["aaa", "bbbb", "c"]
```